# Python csv reader doesn't ignore double quotes

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, csv, parsing

I have a csv file containing lines like:

```
question|"N|1|2|3|4|4|30|2|"N|full_answer
```

and for reading file I do:

```py
with open('questions.csv', 'r') as question_file:
    questions = csv.reader(question_file, delimiter='|', doublequote=False, skipinitialspace=True)
    
    for line in questions:
        print(line)
```

The output of print is:

```
['question', 'N|1|2|3|4|4|30|2|N', 'full_answer']
```

but the output intended is:

```
['question', '"N', '1', '2', '3', '4', '4', '30', '2', '"N', 'full_answer']
```

any solution to ignore double quotes?

Comment: What if you change `doublequote=False` to `True`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 The output is the same.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.doublequote `doublequote=True` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Thank you for finding me an excellent post on SA but I was looking for an official way to do that, not a kind of hack.

Comment: I also noticed that it was asking something different, nevermind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to set [`quotechar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.quotechar) to `'|'` as well:

> A one-character string used to quote fields
> containing special characters, such as the delimiter or quotechar, or
> which contain new-line characters. It defaults to `'"'`.

```
csv.reader(f, delimiter='|', quotechar='|')
...
# [['question', '"N', '1', '2', '3', '4', '4', '30', '2', '"N', 'full_answer']]
```